# Identifying all asp:Image controls in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to find all asp:Image controls in the vb.net code behind to dynamically set the ImageUrl to the same image file. This I can do seperately for each control, but writing 10+ 
`imgQuestion.ImageUrl = cdn.Uri.ToString & "images/question.png"` lines seems a little silly. I do not need to skip any image controls - every single one on the page will be changed. Is there any way to identify all of them without specifying each ID?

The IDs are not all named something similar, such as "Image1", "Image2" but rather "PaymentNote", "search", etc so I cannot loop through all the numbers with something like  `FindControl("Image" & controlNumber)`

Is there another way to do this? I'd prefer to keep the image control IDs as something meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can recursively use `FindControl`, starting from the `Page` and for each control check if it's an `<asp:Image..`.

My own preferred language of choice is C#, so I won't be able to show a VB example. But here's a C# example:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeImageUrls(Page);
    }
    private void ChangeImageUrls(Control ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control subCtrl in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (subCtrl is Image)
            {
                ((Image)subCtrl).ImageUrl = "...";
            }
            if (subCtrl.HasControls())
                ChangeImageUrls(subCtrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. +1 for the combo of a recursive FindControl method (why the hell isn't it baked into .NET anyway...) and checking the control Type. FYI, for VB you can check for a type like this: "If TypeOf (subCtrl) Is TextBox Then ..."

Comment: Your procedure doesn't use `.FindControl()` :)  It uses `.HasControls` and iterates through the `Control.Controls` collection.

Comment: @pseudocoder Excellent point! I'll change the phrasing later when at my computer (on phone now). :-)